# An extra character appears while converting a char array to string in C++

Tags: c++, string, char

So I have written a code where I take three strings at each iteration and store all the combinations of length three(maintaining the order) taking each character from those three strings. I use a char array to make those combinations and then I convert that char array to a string and insert in an unordered_set. While doing so, I encountered a problem where I see an extra character being added at the end of some strings.
Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    char charArr[3];
    string strArr[3];
    unordered_set<string> aSet;
    cin >> n;
    while(n-- > 0) {
        cin >> strArr[0] >> strArr[1] >> strArr[2];
        for(int x=0; x<strArr[0].size(); x++) {
            charArr[0]=strArr[0][x];
            for(int y=0; y<strArr[1].size(); y++) {
                charArr[1]=strArr[1][y];
                for(int z=0; z<strArr[2].size(); z++) {
                    charArr[2]=strArr[2][z];
                    string tempStr(charArr);
                    cout << "Len = " << tempStr.length() << "\n";
                    aSet.insert(tempStr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Check aaz = " << aSet.count("aaz") << "\n";
    for(auto it=aSet.begin(); it!=aSet.end(); it++) {
        cout << *it << "\n";
    }
}
```

Here is a sample input:

```
2
a a z
c a c
```

Here is the output:

```
Len = 4
Len = 3
Check aaz = 0
cac
aaz
```

Here is a picture of how it looks in my pc:

[image]

However when I ran the same code for same input in [ideone](https://ideone.com/WwJYAF), it gave me the correct answer. Which is as follows:

```
Len = 3
Len = 3
Check aaz = 1
cac
aaz
```

Can anybody please explain what's going on here?

N.B: I'm using CodeBlocks and C++14

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: `string tempStr(charArr);`this constructor assume a nul terminated string. Try `string tempStr(charArr, 3);` instead

Comment: @eerorika There's an example in my post. What exactly do you want me to add?

Comment: All questions here must have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors, shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. This question must be [edit]ed, and all links and images removed and replaced with all relevant information, as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text. There's no reason why this one can't, either.

Comment: @SadmanSakib I want you to make the example minimal so that it contains only the things that cause the issue. Does the problem reproduce only when you read input from user? Then perhaps the problem is where you read the input. Otherwise don't read input at runtime. Does the issue reproduce only when you deal with three strings? Perhaps it has something to do with that number. If not, then do the thing only once. Remove everything from the example until it is minimal, but still reproduces the issue.

Comment: @eerorika Sorry for my mistake. I was illustrating what my whole code was doing. I've edited the post now.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I had to add the picture cause the extra character that is added at the end of the string disappears after I post it.

Comment: @MikeVine Thanks. This has solved the problem.